# riot.js how to detect url change

Tags: routes, html5-history, riot.js

To react to an url-change-event, I can set any function to `window.onhashchange` - but `riot.route('targetHash')` will **not** emit / trigger this event.

In comparison: the event is triggered when I change the url manually in the browsers url bar.

**Is there a special way to detect an url change with riot.js**, so I can e.g. trigger a function when the url changes from `...#/oldPage` to `...#/<anything else>`?

riot.js version: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that (or something similar) happen when using some sample code.

the documentation states

> Start listening the url changes and also exec routing on the current
> url.
>
> riot.route.start(true)
>
> This is a shorthand for:
>
> riot.route.start()
>
> riot.route.exec()
>
> **>= v2.3**
>
> Riot doesn’t start its router automatically. DON’T FORGET TO START IT
> BY YOURSELF. This also means that you can choose your favorite router.
> (Note: before v2.3 Riot started the router automatically. The behavior
> was changed)

http://riotjs.com/api/route/#riotroutestartautoexec

I've found using `riot.route.start(true)` fixed it for me